# ArrayList adds null instead of String

Tags: java, arraylist, io, null

I am trying to create a program that is handling a number of cities in an ArrayList which then saves them in a txt file and loads data form the same file if it has been previously created. The problem is that when I hard code the data in the ArrayList the two first Strings (name and country) is null while all the others are fine. Thank you for your time.
Here is the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.io.*;

public class Start {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        City test = new City("Paris","France",0,0,"Sunny",0,123.123,123.123);
        City test2 = new City("Tokyo","Japan",0,0,"Sunny",0,123.123,123.123);
        ArrayList<City> list=new ArrayList<City>();
        list.add(test);
        list.add(test2);
        File file = new File("test.txt");
        if(file.exists()) {
            try{
                load(file, list);
            }catch(IOException e) {
                System.out.println("There was an error loading the file");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            System.out.println("Data have been found in the machine and have been loaded succesfully");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("No data have been found on the machine");
        }
        City obj;
        ListIterator<City> i = list.listIterator();
        while(i.hasNext()) {
            obj = i.next();
            System.out.println(obj.getName()+" "+obj.getCountry());
        }
        save(file,list);


    }

    static void load(File fl, List<City> ct) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fl));
        String str;
        String[] objs = new String[8];
        City city = new City("nothing", "nothing", 0, 0, "nothing", 0, 0, 0);
        while((str=bf.readLine()) != null) {
            objs = str.split(" ");
            city.setName(objs[0]);
            city.setCountry(objs[1]);
            city.setCafeRestaurants(Integer.valueOf(objs[2]));
            city.setLatitude(Double.valueOf(objs[3]));
            city.setLongitude(Double.valueOf(objs[4]));
            city.setMuseums(Integer.valueOf(objs[5]));
            city.setParks(Integer.valueOf(objs[6]));
            city.setWeather(objs[7]);
            ct.add(city);
        }
        bf.close();
    }

    static void save(File fl, List<City> users) throws IOException {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fl);
        City obj;
        ListIterator<City> i = users.listIterator();
        while(i.hasNext()) {
            obj= i.next();
            fw.write(obj.getName()+" "+obj.getCountry()+" "+obj.getCafeRestaurants()+" "+obj.getLatitude()+" "+obj.getLongitude()+" "+obj.getMuseums()+" "+obj.getParks()+" "+obj.getWeather()+"\n");

        }
        fw.close();
    }

}
```

The City class:

```
public class City {
    String name;
    String country;
    int museums;
    int cafeRestaurants;
    String weather;
    int parks;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    public City(String name,String Country,int museums, int cafeRestaurants, String weather, int parks, double latitude, double longitude) {
        this.museums = museums;
        this.cafeRestaurants = cafeRestaurants;
        this.weather = weather;
        this.parks = parks;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }


    public City(int museums, int cafeRestaurants, String weather, int parks) {
        super();
        this.museums = museums;
        this.cafeRestaurants = cafeRestaurants;
        this.weather = weather;
        this.parks = parks;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }


    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
    public int getMuseums() {
        return museums;
    }

    public void setMuseums(int museums) {
        this.museums = museums;
    }

    public int getCafeRestaurants() {
        return cafeRestaurants;
    }

    public void setCafeRestaurants(int cafeRestaurants) {
        this.cafeRestaurants = cafeRestaurants;
    }

    public String getWeather() {
        return weather;
    }

    public void setWeather(String weather) {
        this.weather = weather;
    }

    public int getParks() {
        return parks;
    }

    public void setParks(int parks) {
        this.parks = parks;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    } 

    public void setDefault() {
        this.setCafeRestaurants(0);
        this.setMuseums(0);
        this.setParks(0);
        this.setWeather("Sunny");
    }

}
```

Comment: You do not assign ```name``` and ```country``` in your constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed to initialize and assign the values of name and country variable. Updated constructor for City Class for your reference,

```
public City(String name, String Country, int museums, int cafeRestaurants, String weather, int parks,
        double latitude, double longitude) {
    this.name = name;
    this.country = Country;
    this.museums = museums;
    this.cafeRestaurants = cafeRestaurants;
    this.weather = weather;
    this.parks = parks;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to initialize and assign value to both name and country variable in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor `City(String name,String Country,int museums, int cafeRestaurants, String weather, int parks, double latitude, double longitude)` in the City class, you are not assigning the value of `name` & `Country` to the local variables.

```
public City(String name,String Country,int museums, int cafeRestaurants, String weather, int parks, double latitude, double longitude) {
        this.museums = museums;
        this.cafeRestaurants = cafeRestaurants;
        this.weather = weather;
        this.parks = parks;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
```

Replace the above code with:

```
public City(String name,String Country,int museums, int cafeRestaurants, String weather, int parks, double latitude, double longitude) {
        this.name =name;
        this.country = Country;
        this.museums = museums;
        this.cafeRestaurants = cafeRestaurants;
        this.weather = weather;
        this.parks = parks;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
```

Tip: Use proper naming conventions, e.g., String Country -> String country

(ref.:  https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)